# How can I communicate between nested element directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to make two element directives, `barchart` and `bar` to be used as follows:

```
<barchart>
  <bar ng-repeat='row in some_table'
       label='row.date | date'
       height='row.profit' />
</barchart>
```

I already have some javascript that will draw the appropriate graph on a canvas element given the `(label, height)` pairs. What is the right way of getting the `barchart` directive to read the values from the `bar` directive's attrs?

Comment: Where's your directive?

Comment: ng-repeat is specifically for creating dom elements.  If I'm understanding correctly, you want to just execute your own javascript to draw on the canvas.  In that case wouldn't it be better to skip the bar elements and do something like '<barchart chart-source="row in some_table" label='row.date | date' height='row.profit' />?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your example is a simplification of your problem, here is how you can communicate between these two directives:

```
app.directive('barchart', function($log) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    controller: function($scope) {
      this.drawBar = function(height, date) {
        $log.log('[barchart] Handling charting of bar with label ' + date + ' and height ' + height + '.');
      };
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $log.log('[barchart] Doing DOM transformations...')
    }
  };
});

app.directive('bar', function($log) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    require: '^barchart', // Require an immediate parent element of barchart
    // Requiring the barchart directive gives us access to the bar chart controller instance.
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, barchartCntrl) {
      barchartCntrl.drawBar(scope.row.height, scope.row.date);
    }
  };
});
```

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/80KdD9?p=preview)

Comment: Good assumption, and great answer. Thanks so much!